# Can't install anything after trying and then deleting DeepinDDE

Tags: package-management, dpkg, deepin-desktop-environment

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. After (trying) to purge everything Deepin-related on my system, every time I try and install something from the terminal it includes trying to get me to remove something called "`deepin-anything-server`".

Example:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  clamav-base clamav-freshclam libclamav9 libtfm1
Suggested packages:
  clamav-docs libclamunrar9
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  deepin-anything-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  clamav clamav-base clamav-freshclam libclamav9 libtfm1
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,135 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,450 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

So I press `y` and it does its thing. But every single time this error comes up:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 339973 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing deepin-anything-server (5.0.1-4) ...
userdel: user 'deepin-anything-server' does not exist
Failed on delete user deepin-anything-server
dpkg: error processing package deepin-anything-server (--remove):
 installed deepin-anything-server package post-removal script subprocess returne
d error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 deepin-anything-server
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"
```

If I try to remove this "`deepin-anything-server`" by itself or trying something like "`sudo dpkg --configure -a`" just gives me the same error. I'm kind of a noob and have no idea what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy deepin-anything-server` ? Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 6):

The most straightforward way to solve the problem is low-level package removal by

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all deepin-anything-server
```

and then resume package configuration by

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Tried many solutions but this is the one that solved my issue. Thanks.
I had to also run ```sudo dpkg --purge --force-all deepin-anything-dkms```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by creating the user `deepin-anything-server` typing in the terminal

```
sudo useradd deepin-anything-server
```

and then uninstalling deepin desktop.

Comment: I solved my problem with this answer, @n0rbert answer and Atif ali comment on N0rbert's answer.